# chrome.app.isInstalled always returns false in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

I've successfully put my NaCl app in the Chrome web store, and have placed the following link rel in head:

```
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/[id]" />
```

I have installed successfully the app via onclick several times, but the javascript check for `chrome.app.isInstalled` returns false each time.

I'm not sure what's wrong.

I am using the latest Chrome 30.0.1599.101

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation) is out of date and refers only to [extensions and hosted apps](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/renderer/extensions/app_bindings.cc&l=75). Your NaCl app is not of the supported type. I'd recommend filing a [bug](http://crbug.com/new) about this.

Comment: I think my app is a hosted app? It's on the Chrome web store, so that's automatically a hosted app?

Comment: No, that's an app in the Chrome web store. Chrome web store apps can be hosted or packaged. https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide